# angularjs ng-click and changing view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I am new in angular. I click a button using ng-click. I send it paramter. Every is ok.

```
<div class="item item-text-wrap" ng-click="GetRecordPDF({{item.RecordId}})"></div
```

After this, I need change view and this view's controller will make a service call using "item.RecordId" parameter. 
I hope I will explain what I want to do. Maybe, I make a wrong thing about call ing methods in angular.
How can I make this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: try `ng-click="GetRecordPDF(item.RecordId)"` instead

Answer (score 0):

You no longer need the brackets '{{}}' for variables. You can read more over expressions on this site: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression

Write this now:

```
<div class="item item-text-wrap" ng-click="GetRecordPDF(item.RecordId)"></div>
```